# Error cargando jsx en ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, iis

les comento que estoy trabajando con asp.net core 2.1 y React, siguiendo este tutorial, https://reactjs.net/tutorials/aspnetcore y todo parece ir bien, incluso cuando ejecuto mi proyecto desde Visual Studio funciona sin problemas, pero cuando lo publico al iis local, me presenta los siguientes errores:

Error loading this URI: Protocol error (unknownError): Could not load the source for http://localhost/js/Login/Login.jsx.
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80470002 (NS_BASE_STREAM_CLOSED) [nsIInputStream.available]"  nsresult: "0x80470002 (NS_BASE_STREAM_CLOSED)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://devtools/shared/DevToolsUtils.js :: onResponse :: line 555"  data: no]
Stack: onResponse@resource://devtools/shared/DevToolsUtils.js:555:34
onStopRequest@resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm:123:17
Line: 555, column: 0

ese es el error que puedo ver con las React Dev Tools en el navegador, pero tambien veo este otro error

Loading module from “http://localhost/js/Login/Login.jsx” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“”)

De antemano, muchas gracias por su colaboracion.

he revisado que estoy declarando en el startup el script que voy a utilizar

Answer (score 2):

Este error basicamente te dice que tu servidor no entiende lo que es un JSX

Necesitaras usar la opcion de Publicar de Visual Studio y si con esas no te funciona es posible que tus Bundles esten mal configurados.

Tambien puedes compilar tu codigo usando Webpack (recomendado):
https://reactjs.net/bundling/webpack.html

Comment: Entiendo, la publicacion ya la realizo desde Visual Studio utulizando Web Deploy. voy a revisar el tema de los Bundles y tambien lo de compilar con WebPack. gracias